# Two different notations of the limit distribution of the trace test

Tags: econometrics

I have seen two different versions of the limit distribution of trace test.

If $B_u$ is a standard Brownian motion, then I have seen

$tr\left\{\int_0^1(dB)B'\left[\int_0^1BB'du\right]\int_0^1B(dB')\right\} $ from 'Likelihood-Based Inference in Cointegrated Vector Autoregressive Models' by Søren Johansen

and $tr\left\{\left(\int_0^1B'(dB)\right)'\left[\int_0^1BB'du\right]\int_0^1B(dB')\right\} $ from 'New Introduction to Multiple Time Series Analysis' by Helmut Lütkepohl.

I don't understand why they are equal. I guess that $\int_0^1(dB)B'=\left(\int_0^1B'(dB)\right)'$, but I don't see why.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belong to the mathematics SE as the question is about mathematical operations not about economics or econometrics.

Comment: It's just notation, used in econometrics (not mathematics). The expression $∫_0^1(dB)B′$ has no mathematical meaning. $∫_0^1 B′dB$ is well-defined. It's a matrix whose ij-th entry is the Ito integral $∫_0^1 B_i' dB_j$, where $B_i$ is the i-th component of $B$. You should take the LHS as simply notation for the RHS.